# Angular Redux, Unable to set IAppState to State

Tags: angular, typescript, redux

For the reducer, I am unable to set the reducer to the IAppState interface in my code for redux. Becuase it comes up with this error

```
Argument of type '(state: IAppState, action: any) => IAppState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<IAppState, AnyAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'IAppState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAppState'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAppState'.
```

Because I am trying to set the state as an IAppstate so i can increment the value
app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { IAppState } from './store';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'redux-demo';
  counter:number =0;

  constructor(private ngRedux :NgRedux<IAppState>){

  }
  increment (){
    
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({type:'INCREMENT'});

  }
}
```

store.ts

```
export interface IAppState{
    counter:number;
}

export function rootReducer(state :IAppState, action) : IAppState{
    switch (action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return {counter: state.counter+1}
    }
    return state;
}
```

app.module.ts
Where the error
occurs

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgReduxModule, NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { IAppState, rootReducer } from './store';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgReduxModule
   
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>){
    ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, {counter:0});
  }
 }
```

Thanks
Tuan

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you have an incorrect signature for the reducer that you have defined. The signature expected by the reducer argument of  `ngRedux.configureStore` is `(state: IAppState | undefined, action: any) => IAppState` instead of what you have which is `(state: IAppState, action: any) => IAppState`

In order to fix this, change your reducer definition to something like:

```js
export function rootReducer(state :IAppState | undefined, action) : IAppState {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return {counter: state.counter+1}
    }
    return state;
}
```

But note that you will need to handle the situation where the state argument is undefined.

Comment: But it then comes up with this errorType 'IAppState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAppState'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAppState'.

Comment: Sorry, which error?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant in my answer when I said you need to be careful to ensure that state is defined. Essentially what you need is a fallback or default state that you return in case `state` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
    export interface IAppState {
  counter: number;
}

export const INITIAL_STATE: IAppState = {
  counter: 0,
};

export function rootReducer(
  state: IAppState = INITIAL_STATE,
  action: any
): IAppState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
      return {
        counter: state.counter + 1,
      };
  }
  return state;
}
```